# import mysql.connector error desde la shell debian

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mysqlconnector

Tengo un script que importa `mysql.connector` que funciona correctamente desde el idle, pero cuando trato de ejecutarlos desde la shell del s.o. siempre me lanza el error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/pi/Proyectos/rasSerial.py", line 10, in < module >
>
> > import mysql.connector
>
> ImportError: No module named mysql.connector

Ejecuto el script con su path absoluto, he intentando añadir el camino de mysql con `sys.path.append` pero no hay manera.

No se establecer la variable `PYTHONPATH` con los valores correctos para que me encuentre la librería, si esa fuera la solución.

En fin cualquier idea es de agradecer.

El entorno es Raspbian, con Phyton 3.5.3
Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente buscando en el foro de ingles encontré que es por la versión que se ejecutaba en la shell. Lanzando el script con "phyton3.5 " todo ha funcionado.